# Java Validation constraint of enum + subtype

Tags: java, validation, enums

I'm trying to improve and simplify part of my code using Java Validation constraint (@NonNull, @Min, etc...) but there is one recurrent case in my code where I can't figure out how to use constraint annotation.

Here is an example:

```
public class ResourceIdentifier {
    public enum ResourceType { ARTICLE, USER, COMMENT }

    private @Getter @Setter String id;
    private @Getter @Setter ResourceType type;
}
```

Then I would like to validate MyCommand object so `resourceId` is not null and `resourceId.type` can only be `ARTICLE` or `COMMENT`.

```
public class MyCommand {
    @NotNull
    @Validate(path="#resourceId.type", values={ResourceIdentifier.ResourceType.ARTICLE, ResourceIdentifier.ResourceType.COMMENT})
    private ResourceIdentifier resourceId;

    (...)
}
```

I believe I can achieve this with a custom constraint validation annotation and reflection.

Is there any other simple way ?

EDIT: Imagine I have 10-20 others Command class requiring the type same validation `resourceId.type = {}`

Comment: Is this [tag:lombok] or another framework? You may want to tag it as such.

Comment: You didn't mention what error you get or what other problems you have with your program. But shouldn't the values be the actual enums? `ResourceIdentifier.ResourceType.ARTICLE` etc?

Comment: Good point @RealSkeptic . I updated the question. I don't have any error, I'm just wondering what's the most effective way to implement the `@Validate` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an assertion constraint (this is a method inside `MyCommand`):

```
@AssertTrue(message="Only Comment and Article are allowed as resource type")
public boolean isResourceIdValid() {
   return this.resourceId.getType() == ResourceIdentifier.ResourceType.ARTICLE 
          || this.resourceId.getType() == ResourceIdentifier.ResourceType.COMMENT;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the main problem is that I have 50 different commands and more than 10 has the constraint `resourceId.type = {enum}`. I'm wondering how to leverage constraint annotation to avoid code duplication.

Comment: You may want to implement a custom validator, but that won't remove the need of declaring metadata on each class, unless you (perhaps) declare the constraint in a common (maybe abstract) superclass and make that superclass use a field value obtained via an overridden method. Either way, you'll need to repeat the constraint declaration, or you'll have to declare some other enum/data structure that maps command types to their respective resource type sets. IMO, an assert method is easier to test and to maintain... But that's up to you.